# How can I rotate and then save an image with Emacs 27.1?

Tags: images

It's nice that 27.1 has in-built image rotation.  No dependency on ImageMagick for that.  However, it seems to only allow rotation for viewing (`r`/`l`) while I don't see any way of saving that rotated image.  Upon rotation I don't see the buffer marked dirty.

Am I missing something or is it simply unsupported?

More general solutions of saving a buffer's contents as-is would be nice too.  I'm uninformed here.

Comment: If you are missing something, I'm missing it too: I don't know of a way to save a transformed image.